# imagemagick: translate a .png image by dx, dy pixels

Tags: imagemagick

I can't find the docs in imagemagick that pertain to translating an image by dx,dy pixels.

Can someone help me? I want to produce an image that's the same size as the original, just shifted, and with the new pixels set to color X.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for

`convert originalimage.png  -virtual-pixel colorofnewpixel -distort Affine 'originalx,originaly newx,newy' translatedimage.png`

This is further documented with examples at [ImageMagick v6 Examples -Distorting Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/) under the **Distortions Using Control Points** heading.